# Vim sorting by virtual column

Tags: sorting, vim

Why can't I sort the below table on its third column?

Column 1 sorts alright with `:sort /.*\%1v/`:

```
Audi       ***     ****      **
BMW        *****   ***       *****
Mercedes   ****    *****     ***
Opel       ***     ***       *
```

Column 2 also sorts alright with `:sort /.*\%2v/`:

```
BMW        *****   ***       *****
Mercedes   ****    *****     ***
Opel       ***     ***       *
Audi       ***     ****      **
```

But Column 3 doesn't sort with `:sort /.*\%3v/`:

```
BMW        *****   ***       *****
Audi       ***     ****      **
Opel       ***     ***       *
Mercedes   ****    *****     ***
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're fooled by a misconception: The `\%v` atom specifies *character* columns (but doesn't consume them as a match); I think you want to sort based on whitespace-separated text / what is called "columns" in a newspaper or table.

I.e. your first example sorts on the characters B, A, O, and M; the second on M, u, p, e, **not** on the `*`'s (depending on your locale, uppercase letters sort before lowercase).

If you have `:set ruler`, you see the current colum in the lower right corner. In your example, the third text column starts at position 20, so you'd have to use

```
:%sort /.*\%20v/
```

to sort on the third text column.

For Vim, *virtual column* means screen columns, measured by what one (single-width) character occupies. There's also *column*, which mean (somewhat unintuitively) byte counts of the character's representation. This distinction matters for non-ASCII, non-printable, and the `<Tab>` character.

Comment: Hmm, OK. I'll try to improve my typing speed for next time ;-)

Comment: Thanks, Ingo. You've nailed it. But then my next question: is it possible in Vim to do the kind of sort I'm after, i.e. by the 'newspaper column'? What if I select a block of the asterisk with `Ctrl-G` and do `'<,'>sort`? Will this work?

Comment: That's not so easy. You can insert the current column into the command with `<C-r>=virtcol('.')<CR>`. And have a look at the [csv.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2830) plugin; it has a `:Sort` command.

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing wrong is considering

```
**
*****
***
*
```

as a "virtual column".

A "virtual column" is a single-cell wide column.

In your first snippet, these are the columns you match:

```
\%1v  \%2v  \%3v

A     u     d
B     M     W
M     e     r
O     p     e
```

So your lines are not ordered by number of asterisks but alphabetically.

I've tried the following commands to order by number of asterisks but they don't seem to be reliable.

```
:%sort /.*\%12c.*\%16c/
:%sort /.*\%20c.*\%24c/
:%sort /.*\%30c.*\%34c/
```

Comment: I like your "visual" explanation! The reason your sort attempt didn't work is that you seem to have missed that the `/{pattern}/` (unintuitively) covers that part that is _skipped_.

Comment: @IngoKarkat: Yes, completely missed that part. Thank you!